# Renaming a parent class property in subclass

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6

In es2015, if I have base class to represent a `List` that looks like this:

```
class List {
  constructor(data){
    this.data = data
  }

  sortBy(attribute){
    return this.data.sort((a,b) => {
      return (a[attribute] < b[attribute]) ? 1 : -1;
    })
  }
  get count() { return this.data.length }
}
```

Then I might want to subclass that base class with a less generic kind of data, namely, if I am an elf, toys:

```
class ToyList extends List {
  constructor(toys){
    super(toys);
    this.toys = toys;
  }
}
```

At this point `ToyList` is no different from `List`, except for the name. But if you look at an instantiation of `ToyList`, it has *both* `data` and `toys` properties. These refer to the same array, in terms of conceptualizing the point of a `ToyList`, `data` doesn’t make much sense.

If I make a `ToyList`, I have both `.data` and a `.toys` attributes:

```
tl = new ToyList(['truck', 'plane', 'doll'])
Object { data: Array[3], toys: Array[3] }
```

Then my `tl` has both a `data` and a `toys` attribute. They’re both references to the same array, but what I would like is for the subclass to *only* have the `toys` reference.

Here’s another example which utilizes a method on the base class:

```
class Todos extends List {
  constructor(todos){
    super(todos);
    this.todos = todos;
  }

  get byPriority(){
    return this.todos.sortBy('priority')
  }
}

var thingsToDo = [
  {task: 'wash the dog', priority: 10},
  {task: 'do taxes', priority: 1},
  {task: 'clean the garage', priority: 0}

]

var todos = new Todos(thingsToDo);
todos.byPriority
```

This would be nice, because then I could just refer to `.byPriority` to get a sorted version of the list which is very specific to this particular kind of data. But I can’t see how I can make that happen, because

But what I get is:

```
TypeError: this.todos.sortBy is not a function
```

So to summarize, what I want is a way to refer to to base class properties with a name which is specific to the semantics of the subclass, without losing the methodology of the base class.

Comment: Well, why do you inherit from List, if you don't want the functionality that List provides? Seems like your Abstraction needs a re-evaluation !?

Comment: I have added a couple more methods to the base class to make the point clearer. Of course there would be other methods on the Collection, the sorts of things you can do with a Backbone collection, for instance (sort, search, save, whatever). My question is how to override a given property on the base class so that the derived class can have domain-specific methods and properties, and nothing else.

Comment: Nothing against adding additional functionality on the derived classes.
But as soon as you don't apply your collection to the `data`-property all the additional functionality of the List will fail, and you'll have to wrap or re-implement them for the derived classes; like you've done with `get toyCount()` instead of using `get count()`. The whole approach makes no sense, and only adds complexity. I'll add an example of a better approach.

Comment: `But what I get is: TypeError: this.todos.sortBy is not a function` sortBy is a method of your List-class, but this.todos is not a List, it's a private property of the Todos-class and of type Array, wich doesn't implement your methods. That are exactly the problems I'm talking about. You would have to re-implement the sortBy-function on Todos to sort the todos-property instead of the data-property, and so on... for every subclass you write. Take a look at my Answer, i've written an example Code, that would walk around this whole Problem.

Answer (score 2):

referencing our discurrion in the comments, a better implementation (imo), extensible and avoiding the problem you asked about

```
var AP = Array.prototype; //just lazy

class List {
    constructor(elements){
        for(var i = 0, j = (elements && elements.length)|0; i<j; ++i)
            this[i] = elements[i];
        //use length instead of count, stay compatible with the Array-methods
        //will make your life easier
        this.length = i;
    }

    length: 0

    sortBy(attr){
        return this.sort(function(a,b){
            return (a[attribute] < b[attribute]) ? 1 : -1
        });
    }

    //some functions have to be wrapped, to produce a List of the right type
    filter(fn){
        return new (this.constructor)(AP.filter.call(this, fn));
    }

    clone(){ return new (this.constructor)(this) }
}

//some functions can simply be copied from Array
//no need to re-implement or even wrap them.
List.prototype.sort = AP.sort;
List.prototype.push = AP.push;
List.prototype.pop = AP.pop;
```

the subclass

```
class ToyList extends List {
  constructor(toys){
    //maybe you want to filter the input, before you pass it to the list
    //or convert it, or whatever, it's all up to you
    super(toys && AP.filter.call(toys, v=>v instanceof Toy));
  }

  //... additional functionality
}
```

and an example usage

```
class Toy {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}

var a = new ToyList([
  new Toy("foo"), 
  new Toy("bar"), 
  "not a toy",
  new Toy("baz") 
])

console.log(a instanceof ToyList, a);

var b = a.filter(toy => toy.name.charAt(0) === "b");

console.log(b instanceof ToyList, b);
```

**Edit: added your Example with the Todos**

```
class Todos extends List {
    //don't even need a constructor, since I simply want to pass 
    //the array to the parent-constructor

    //don't use getter for functionality, use methods!
    byPriority(){
        return this.sortBy('priority');
    }
}

var thingsToDo = [
  {task: 'wash the dog', priority: 10},
  {task: 'do taxes', priority: 1},
  {task: 'clean the garage', priority: 0}
]

var todos = new Todos(thingsToDo);
todos.byPriority()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The last line, `console.log(todos.byPriority())`, includes `length` as an “element.” What your approach looks like to me is essentially recreating arrays, with each element in the list added as an attribute of `List` itself. This is an interesting approach (especially when it will become possible to actually do `class List extends Array`), but it’s a solution to quite a different problem than my original one.

Answer (score 2):

> `ToyList` has both `data` and `toys` properties. These refer to the same array, in terms of conceptualizing the point of a `ToyList`, `data` doesn’t make much sense.

There's your actual problem: your `ToyList` doesn't make sense as a subclass of `List`.

If (for any reasons) your class should be similar to `List`, but not have a `data` property, then **it's not a subclass** any more. It would violate the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

---

Now what are your options?

- as you already considered, you can make it a subclass in which the more specific `.toys` property  is an alias for `.data`. This is perfectly fine, but you can't avoid having that `data` property there as well.
- you might want to outiright scrap that `data` property and store elements directly on the object. Your `List` class looks like "Array but with useful helper functions". If that was your intention, you should consider making it an actual subclass of `Array`. @Thomas's answer goes in that direction.
- you might want to favor [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) over inheritance. You've already used the concept - your `List` instances contain `Array`s in their `data` properties. If you have a `Wishlist` or `Toylist` or whatever, that deal specifically with whishes or toys and have corresponding methods for them, you can simply store a `List` instance in their `.toys` slot.
  You actually seemed to expect your `TodoList` to work like that, given the invocation of `this.todos.sortBy('priority')` (where `this.todos` would be a `List`). On an subclass, just `this.sortBy('priority')` would do the job.
- I didn't really get how your `ToyList` is a specialisation of `List`. If there is nothing special about it but the name, maybe you actually don't need a different class alltogether. If JavaScript had generics or type variables, you'd use a `List<Toy>`, but it doesn't so you can just use `List`s directly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a lot of different problems.

Your list has a problem with the definition of `sortBy`, you need to take 3 cases in account, like this:

```
class List {
  constructor(data){ this.data = data; }
  sortBy(attribute){
    console.log("sortBy");
    return this.data.sort( (a,b) => {
      if (a[attribute] < b[attribute]) return -1;
      if (a[attribute] > b[attribute]) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
  }
  get count() { return this.data.length; }
}
```

Now you can extend the `List`, and if you want to name `data` as `toys` then define a `get` method named `toys()` to return the data. It may strange to you, but if you subclass `List` then you should use `data` (if not, don't subclass it). There is an alternative: you can delete `data` attribute and then create `toys` but alas, designing a `sortBy` method in `List` would be difficult (or use a second parameter to name the array to sort?). So, let's use the first suggestion:

```
class ToyList extends List {
  constructor(toys){ super(toys); }
  get toys() { return this.data; }
}
```

Let do the same for `Todos`:

```
class Todos extends List {
  constructor(todos){ super(todos); }
  get todos() { return data; }
  get byPriority(){
    return this.sortBy('priority');
  }
}
```

The definition of `byPriority` is a little bit weird as it has a border effect (sorting the elements). I (personally) would write it as a *standard* method.

Then let's make some tests:

```
var thingsToDo = [
  {task: 'wash the dog', priority: 10},
  {task: 'do taxes', priority: 1},
  {task: 'clean the garage', priority: 3}
];

var tl = new ToyList(['truck', 'plane', 'doll']);
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
  console.log(tl.toys[i]); // access the *pseudo* toys attribute
}

var todos = new Todos(thingsToDo);
var r = todos.byPriority; // access the *pseudo*  byPriority attribute (border effect: sorting internal data)

for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
  console.log(todos.data[i].priority);
}
```

May I suggest you to have a little more read about OOP and inheritance? The point of need to subclass but removing data attribute is certainly a bad design.

Comment: Thanks for this. What do you mean by “standard” method?

Comment: Your definition of `byPriority` authorizes the attribute access syntax, which is somehow weird (at least to me). I would prefer the method call. Anyway, this may not be very important here.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, a better approach, if possible, would be to treat the List class are pure virtual, Meaning you will never create an instance of that class, but only just extend from it.

Pure virtual classes are not supposed to have constructors, and the methods are to assume certain properties exist. However, you could infact use the constructor to set the name that the base class should use for the 'data' property.

```
class List {
 constructor(keyName) { this.keyName = keyName }
 sortBy(attr) { return this[this.keyName].sort(...) } 
}

class ToyList extends List {
  constructor('toys') {
    super(toys)
    this.toys = toys;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really vague.

Comment: sorry, I got busy halfway through answering lol. Updated with some code to illustrate what I mean